# play framework inter-app communication

Tags: playframework

Since Play currently supports using only one database per application, what's the best way for one Play application to access the data of another?  Are there any better methods than simply fetching data in JSON format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the best method is to use a REST call to interact with the other application (if the other application is calling the Play one) or use the WS library to call webservices of the target application if you want to call it from Play.

Personally, I dislike the idea of writing stuff to a "common database/table" as this means both applications must be completely aware of the structure of the table, and any changes on one end will imply changes on the table and the other side. It also means you create a specific channel between these 2 applications that it will be hard to reuse if, in the future,  you want more applications to take part in it.

I would favor using REST (preferably) or SOAP for this. It will decouple the applications and make it simpler (specially with Play). And if for some reason the target app doesn't support REST/SOAP, a simple wrapper application to manage the communication would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Be patient for a few days IMO because the multidb support is incoming very soon.
Apparently Morten Kjetland has implemented it and gonna commit it after some verifications...
http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/598e70249c56e17e?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest looking at the multidb module

http://www.playframework.org/modules/multidb

But,I have just checked my Twitter account and Play 1.2 has been released.